# Django ModelForm save only if text entered matches

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class test1(models.Model):
    write = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.write
```

forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = test1
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.objects.write == 'banana':
                form.save(commit=True)
            else:
                return "Wrong name"
            return render(request,'app_one/index.html')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

I would like to save the form only if user enters banana in the write field of NameForm.
can I use     if form.objects.write == 'banana':
                        form.save(commit=True)

Comment: No, you should use .data` or `.cleaned_data`, depending on whether you first want to perform normalization. So `form.cleaned_data['write'] == 'banana'`.

Comment: Furthermore you can not `return 'wrong name'` directly, it needs to be wrapped in a response.

Comment: Where does this `.objects` actually orginates from? Models have a `.objects`, but *not* `forms.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with your previous question, this appears to show some confusion about what forms are for and how they work. Nevertheless, if you want to prevent saving depending on the value of a field, by definition that is validation, and belongs in the form itself. So:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_write(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['write']
        if value != 'banana': 
            raise forms.ValidationError('wrong value')
        return value

    class Meta():
        model = test1
        fields = '__all__'
```